Как сравнивать double в C++ не на равенство?
        double x = *(*(array) + i);
        double y = *(*(array + 1) + i);
        double x_squared = pow(x, 2);
        double y_squared = pow(y, 2);

        if ((x_squared + y_squared < 9) && \
            (x > 0 && y > 0 && y_squared > 2.25 - pow(x - 1.5, 2)) || \
            (x < 0 && y < 0 && y_squared > 2.25 - pow(x + 1.5, 2)) || \
            (x < 0 && y > 0) || \
            (x > 0 && y < 0))

Очевидно, что на равенство double в плюсах сранивается с помощью эпсилона.
Писал лабу, где нужно работать с double и делать проверки, что точка принадлежит заданной области.
Преподаватель предъявляет, что не использую эпсилон.
Где только не искал код, который при сравнении двух даблов использует эпсилон.
Как его здесь реализовать? На ум пришло только что-то подобное:
if ((x_squared + y_squared < 9 - epsilon) && \
    ((x > 0) && (y > 0) && (y_squared > 2.25 - pow(x - 1.5, 2) + epsilon)) || \
    ((x < 0) && (y < 0) && (y_squared > 2.25 - pow(x + 1.5, 2) + epsilon)) || \
    ((x < 0) && (y > 0)) || \
    ((x > 0) && (y < 0)))


возможный дубликат

Важно понимать, что сравнение с использованием эпсилона (и его величина) нужно только если вы сравниваете 2 числа, полученных разными вычислениями (разными частями программы). Если на основе одних и тех же исходных данных проводить вычисление результата одним и тем же кодом, то независимо от количества попыток результат будет одним и тем же (и тогда эпсилон абсолютно не нужен)

допустим, но преподаватель требует. я как и вы, не вижу в этом смысла. не могли бы вы подсказать реализацию данного кода, поскольку в своем я не уверен
